# How can i print the elements of a dictionary if an input string matches with a key?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the keys are some strings and they hold string values. Now I want to write a code which takes input from the user and if the input matches with any of the keys, prints the value contained in the keys. How do I access the elements contained in the keys and print them?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to access keys in your dictionary, just print the value, using your user input as key:

```
if user_input in your_dictionary :
    print your_dictionary[user_input]
else :
    print user_input, 'is not found in the dictionary'
```

(you need `if` check to avoid throwing an `Exception` in case when your user input is not in your dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
dict['key']
```

where key is your input string. A dictionary works like an array except rather than numbers you can use a string to get to the data

Answer (score 0):

Your program should be something like this

```
a_dict = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}
key = input('what key: ')

if key in a_dict:
    print('the value of key {} is {}'.format(key, a_dict[key]))

else:
    print('key {} is not in the dict'.format(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `get` function of python dictionaries like this

```
my_dict = {1: 'One', 2:'Two', 3:'Three'}

my_key = input("Enter your key")

print my_dict.get(my_key,'Key not found')
```

See the examples [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm).